# IBM Cloud: Public IP ranges

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, ibm-cloud-tools

are the public IP ranges being used by IBM Cloud documented anywhere? I have a customer who would want to look at whitelisting these IPs in their VPN firewall

Answer (score 2):

The IP ranges are not documented and are subject to change.

Depending on the service(s) or the requirements there could be technical solutions, including direct link.